# c# Generics : Can I combine overloaded methods into one with different return/input data types?

Tags: c#, generics, overloading, type-conversion, strong-typing

I have 4 static helper methods I want to combine into one if possible. Each method is identical aside from the input parameter data type, and setting a value in the ReturnDto and the ReturnDto type. I'm fairly new to Generics but not even sure if this is doable in an efficient matter other than having 4 strongly typed methods.

```
private static ReturnDto<int> MethodName(int val)
private static ReturnDto<string> MethodName(string val)
private static ReturnDto<bool> MethodName(bool val)
private static ReturnDto<DateTime> MethodName(DateTime val)
{
    //do some stuff here...
    return new ReturnDto<DateTime> { Val = val, Val2 = val2, Val3 = val3 };
}
```

Comment: what are val2 and val3 in your example?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes:

```
private static ReturnDto<T> MethodName<T>(T val)
```

If you substitute `T` ([generic type parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/generic-type-parameters)) with any specific type you will get the method you expect. Think of `T` as a placeholder for any type. If not *any* type is valid then you can constraint it to comply with certain rules; read [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/constraints-on-type-parameters) for more information.

Also worth noting, is that type inference allows you to call this method without actually having to state the generic type:

```
var returnDto = MethodName(1); //instead of MethodName<int>(1)
```

`T` is inferred through the type of `val` which is `int`; the compiler has enough information to figure out the type of `T` with you needing to explicitly state it.

Comment: You should also note that by providing a specific type as the parameter, you don't need to specify the generic type when calling it.

Comment: It's so funny to look back on this now. I was 100% green on generics and a colleague made it sound so much more complicated than it is. Had I taken 15 minutes to really look it up I would have not even posted this!